# Сигналы слоты qt

Tags: c++, qt

Задача состоит в том, что есть два класса. В экземпляре одного из принимаются на вход данные (например чтение из файла) и после обработки передается в экземпляр другого класса. Первый класс, который формирует и передает данные наследуется от QThread. Второй является наследником QWidget. В итоге при использовании сигнально-слотового соединения в консоль выдается следующее сообщение.

> QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QByteArray&' (Make
>   sure 'QByteArray&' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)

Сигнал первого класса:

```
void sendBytes(QByteArray& arr);
```

Слот второго класса:

```
void receiveBytes(QByteArray&);
```

Соединение:

```
connect(ctch, SIGNAL(sendBytes(QByteArray&)), this, SLOT(receiveBytes(QByteArray&)));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наследоваться от `QThread` плохо, читайте как правильно делать в [Threads Events QObjects](http://wiki.qt.io/Threads_Events_QObjects). Конкретно по Вашей ошибке: Вы передаёте lvalue-ссылку сквозь потоки, что **крайне** небезопасно. Qt не может упаковать такую ссылку и передать в другой поток, отсюда и ошибка. Используйте ссылку на константу или передачу по значению.

Comment: То есть передавать и принимать QByteArray, вместо QByteArray& ?
В той ссылке, которую вы предоставили ниже указан пример явного наследования от QThread.

Comment: @Валентин, да. Так Вы весь текст прочитайте, а не выборочно ;)

Answer (score 1):

QByteArray является [***implicit sharing***](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html) классом. Это означает что данный класс является оберткой вокруг *указателя с подсчетом ссылок*, реализующий поведение ***copy-on-write***. При создании экземпляра-копии увеличивается счетчик ссылок. При изменении содержимого создается новая полная копия объекта с вносимыми изменениями для экземпляра где вносятся изменения, все остальные экземпляры не изменяются. Экземпляры классов с подсчетом ссылок бессмысленно передавать по ссылке, т.к. экономии при этом не достигается.

Передавайте QByteArray по значению